# add transition ease to slider

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions

i am trying to get an easing effect to my slider, so that the images are loaded 1s and 2s respectively within a slider.

here is the code i have so far

http://jsfiddle.net/kNZLx/

i would like the .figure to have a delay of 1s and the .shadow figure to load 1s after that and slide in from right-to left.

my sass file is something like:

```
  .shadow {
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    @include single-transition($ease:2s) {
      transition: $ease;
    }
  }
```

but the code does not function!

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before with key frames, have a look http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst
{
0%   {background: red;}
25%  {background: yellow;}
50%  {background: blue;}
100% {background: green;}
}
```

Here you can set the % of the duration based on the entire animation you want it to happen.